# Minify and package Angular

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm trying to create a dist folder using `grunt.js` and `uglify`.

I'm now trying to minify my js files but now i'm getting instantiation errors.

```
    Failed to instantiate module achApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:5:26440
    at http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:6:11336
    at f (http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:5:26888)
    at j (http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:6:10908)
    at http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:6:11077
    at f (http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:5:26888)
    at j (http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:6:10908)
    at Pa (http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:6:12940)
    at g (http://kirra.dev/app/js/vendor.min.js:6:1577
```

How can I troubleshoot this and what is the best way to start packaging and minifying all the js files as now everything is all on one line?

I am creating a vendor.min.js file with bootstrap.js, jquery.min.js angular.js, all my angular components.js. (basically all my bower)

Then i'm creating a main.min.js with all of my services, controllers and factories.(basically my app)

The code below is in my factories and controllers to stop uglify from renaming my functions but it does not seem to be working

```
   BookController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'bookFactory','$sessionStorage', 'Guid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use the "mangle" option. This will do the job.

```
grunt.initConfig({
      uglify: {
        options: {
          mangle: false
        },
        my_target: {
          files: {
            'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input.js']
          }
        }
      }
    });
```